# Using SPP Layer as input and Removing Layers before that in Yolov5

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolov5

I got features extracted from yolov5 from SPP layer using farward hook. I have applied some methods to it and now I want to use this resultant SPP features in the place of another yolov5 model but that model should start from taking Input from SPP layer till end and give predictions.

Thats how I extracted Features from SPP layer:

```py
class FeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        self.features_2 = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[0:])

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.features_2(x)

# initialize YOLOv5 model
model_A2 = torch.hub.load('yolov5', 'custom', source='local', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)

# register hook to extract features from SPP layer
spp_layer_2 = next(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, nn.Conv2d), model.modules())) # returns SPP   layer
features_2 = None

def hook_function(module, input, output):
    global features_2
    features_2 = output

h = spp_layer_2.register_forward_hook(hook_function)

# extract features from an image
img = Image.open('ra169_2.jpg')
input_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()(img).unsqueeze(0)
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_tensor)

# Extracted features from SPP layer of YOLOv5 model can be found in the `features` variable
print(features_2)

# Don't forget to remove the hook after you're done with it!
h.remove()
```

I have tried using this but somehow remove the layers above SPP and use SPP but cannot able to do so

```py
class CustomYOLOv5(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomYOLOv5, self).__init__()
        self.model = torch.hub.load('yolov5', 'custom', source='local', path='best.pt', force_reload=True)
    self.model.model = nn.Sequential(*list(self.model.model.children())[4:])  # Remove layers before SPP

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

# Create an instance of the custom YOLOv5 model
model_custom = CustomYOLOv5()

# Pass the averaged tensor through the custom model
with torch.no_grad():
    predictions = model_custom(tensor1)

print(predictions)
```

Comment: "cannot able" is insufficient. please provide a complete traceback, if there is one, or show/describe the error in any suitable way. [mre]. also make sure your code is syntactically correct. in python, indentation is syntax. I already fixed your second block of code. the first one defines a `FeatureExtractor` that is never used.